# Bootstrap NavBar ccs3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm testing the bootstrap navbar and how I do not know much about styles. When I click the icon, a dotted frame appears outside the image boundary, as follows:

[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suNdI.jpg)

I know this is related to the page style, but do not know how to solve. Below is the exact code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="lib/img/mig.png">
   </a>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </button>
  <h1 class="navbar-header" href="#">Home</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">
  <br>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
   <li class="active"> 
    <a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class=""> 
    <a href="#">About</a>
   </li>
   <li class=""> 
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </li>
   <li class=""> 
    <a href="#">Maps</a>
   </li>       
  </ul>
  </br>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wheel is standard browsers to "links"
To resolve you have two options
- Include it in your tag

```
a: active {
outline: none;
}
```

- Include a height with the same height as your image

  .navbar-brand {
  height: 60px;
  }

Helped?

Comment: Yes, a lot.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this rule in your css file

```
a {
   outline: none;
}
```

source: [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)

Answer (score 0):

The first posted answer may solve the problem, but it would also affect every anchor tag on the page, which seems a bit overkill.

I'd suggest this instead:

```
.navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```